Ngx-Mask transform input into a decimal number
How can I use ngx-mask to transform an input into a decimal number so that the user sees it, for example, 123 becomes 123.00, 142.1 becomes 142.10, and 73.30 remains 73.00?
I have already tried everything.
I would also like to know if I can extract the total number of digits and the number of decimal places into variables.

please share the code you tried also, shouldn't it be "73.30 remains 73.30"?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Try adding: [leadZero]="true"
<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" maxlength="19" formControlName="basePrice" autocomplete="off" prefix="R$ " mask="separator.2" decimalMarker="," [leadZero]="true" thousandSeparator="." separatorLimit="9999999999">
